# How to Enable document.designMode = 'on' only for A Specific Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure how can I enable document.designMode = 'on' for only specific elements, for example, h1 and paragraphs, without allowing the whole website to be edited.

Example Html. (I want the JS to work on h1's and p's.)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello World<title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Det Spaghet</h3>
   <p>Lorem Ipsum Det Spaghet, and kthetup super market</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
document.designMode = 'on'
```

Comment: Share your code with us

Comment: Yes, I did the change.

Comment: [HTMLElement.contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

Answer (score 5):

Did you tried `contenteditable="true"` ?

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<h3>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Det Spaghet</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Det Spaghet, and kthetup super market</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I add this to a class, for example, class =  "title"?

Answer (score 2):

use this code `<div contenteditable="true">This text can be edited!</div>`
and use `document.designMode = "off";`

or You can apply custom settings with jQuery For example `$('.title').attr('contenteditable','true');`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  button{
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius:3px;
    color:white;
  }
  .color_red{
  background:red;
  }
   .color_green{
  background:green;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Document designMode off Property</h1>

<p class="title">The designMode property sets whether the document is not editable or not.</p>

<p class="title">This document is not editable!</p>

   
<div class="mycls">
  This text can be edited!
</div>

<button id="setEditable" class="color_green">Set tag p Editable</button>
<button id="removeEditable" class="color_red">Remove tag p Editable</button>
<script>
document.designMode = "off";

  $('#setEditable').click(function () {
    $('.title').attr('contenteditable','true');
 });
 
 
  $('#removeEditable').click(function () {
     $('.title').attr('contenteditable','false');
 });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Test this code. it is work.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I add this to a class, for example, class =  "title"?

Comment: @akaI-Know I changed the code so you can make changes with JavaScript and jQuery